# Value returned by property method in django not getting stored in database. How to make this possible?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In my models.py file I have a property method which returns a value and I need to store that value in the database field.

`

```
class bug(models.Model):
    ......
    .......
    id_of_bug = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank= False, null= False)
    
    @property
    def bug_id(self):
        bugid = "BUG{:03d}".format(self.pk)
        self.id_of_bug = bugid
        return bugid




Tried to store the value in database using self method, but not working.
```

Comment: The assignment `self.id_of_bug = bugid` doesn't really happen until you access your property. Although you don't even need to store that value in the database, why bother? Just remove that extra field, the property should be enough if you need it only for display purposes...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat What if I want this dummy id while I export this database to excel?

Comment: I see the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you'll find it better to ask the X question instead of the Y question you just asked.

Comment: I want this id to be saved in my database so  whenever I export this database to excel this parameter will be included as a column. So I believe I asked the X question. @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: Your X question is "How do I export this data into excel so that the ID shows in the form `BUG<id>`. The Y question the one you asked is "How do I make it so that the id field is copied into another field from a property". Do you see the difference?

Comment: Can we come to the point where I can save the value returned by the property method inside database?

Answer (score 0):

I would try use a property setter that updates the table value:

```py
class bug(models.Model):
    ......
    .......
    id_of_bug = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank= False, null= False)
    
    @property
    def bug_id(self):
        bugid = "BUG{:03d}".format(self.pk)
        self.id_of_bug = bugid
        return bugid

    @bug_id.setter
    def bug_id(self, value):
        # value = some_transform(value)
        self.id_of_bug = value
        self.save(update_fields=['id_of_bug'])
```

Comment: sorry. Its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try signals to store data

```
class bug(models.Model):
    ......
    .......
    id_of_bug = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank= False, null= False)
    
    @property
    def bug_id(self):
        bugid = "BUG{:03d}".format(self.pk)
        return bugid


from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=bug)
def save_bugid(sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.id_of_bug = instance.bug_id
        instance.save()
```

Comment: TypeError at /upload/
unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__.Throws this error while object creation.

Comment: Edited. Try this method this will works

Comment: Sorry. The error still remains.

Comment: i thing i missed editing 'sender=Bug' use 'sender=bug' according your model
which are you used 'sender=Bug' or 'sender=bug' ?

Comment: I spotted that but that's not the error. Its still the same that I mentioned above.